# To filter/subset a data frame based on character vector with R

Tags: r, vector, filter, character

I have a data frame look like this :

```
data.frame' 45678 obs. of 130 variables
    $ Seqeunce    : chr  "AAAAAIGGR" "AAAAAIGGRPNYYGNEGGR" "AAAAASSNPGGGPEMVR" ...
    $ IDs         : chr   "1404" "4963" "3012" "1404;6181" "1404;6185" ...
```

I want filter the data that contains IDs of 1404 with code below:

```
data.frame.new <- data.frame[data.frame$IDs %in% 1404,]
```

Unfortunately, this way I cant get data contains "1404;6181" I tried to split the data with

```
 strsplit(data.frame$IDs,";", fixed = TRUE, perl = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)
```

then filter again, but didnt work , any suggestions??

Comment: Use `df[grepl("1404".df$IDs),]`, I think. Also, I think you really don't want to name your data.frame "data.frame".

Comment: thanks alot, as i said below, there is problem of getting IDs such as 14041 or 11404... is it possible search values between ";" ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the convenient

```
data.frame.new <- data.frame[grepl('(^|;)1404($|;)', data.frame$IDs), ]
```

Comment: thanks alot, it woks but in redundant way, the thing is each IDs represent one protein, and there are protein IDs 14041 or 11404, it filter those ones as well, it is possible search data.frame$IDs vector between ";" so i will get the ones only containing 1404 ?